# React + Non-react third-party libraries

Tags: reactjs, web, web-frameworks, metro-ui-css

I have a fundamental question related to React.

For example, i want to use ths third-party libray: https://metroui.org.ua/stepper.html#_stepper_events (example component, that has special callbacks) with react. 
[image]
But this library doesnt have react bindings. So, i want to find out the right way to use it. 
Should i use it with JQuery? With library, that shipped with this framework? (Metro.js in this way https://metroui.org.ua/events.html) Should i use this library at all?

Thank you in advance!